# Java resizing my splitter frame

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, resize, splitter

I have a jDialog with a splitter inside it.

One side has a tree while the other side has a frame. Whenever I use setVisible(false) to hide the frame, the splitter resizes to filled the entire screen with the tree.

Is there anyway to keep the tree side of the splitter the same size whether the frame is hidden or not?

Comment: More info:

I am coding this in myEclipse and using the Matisse editor to make the UI easier to deal with which automatically puts everything into a GroupLayout.

I was hoping there was just a trick with splitter that I was unaware of, hope the only way isnt to recode it in BorderLayout.

Comment: What is a splitter, I've never heard of it? What is a "frame". You can't add a "frame" to a JDialog. Use proper terms to describe your problem if you want help. Don't make us guess what you are talking about. Better still post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) so the question is clear.

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to myEclipse and this Matisse editor. My Dialog has a Split Pane: On the left side there is a tabbed pane populated with a JTree On the right side I am adding a panel with misc menu options including a "cancel" button which hides the panel again. When I hit that button and the .setVisible(false) is run, the split pane resizes the left side to fill the entire dialog until I reopen the panel on the right.

Comment: What I meant  is you don't have to change to the borderlayout... you have to add panel with it's layout set to be the Borderlayout to the right side of your split pane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish that would be **adding panel with BorderLayout instead of a "frame" and then adding frame to it**. So when you hide the "frame" panel stays and keeps its size.